# How to interpret this date format?

Tags: javascript, date, format

I just found a date format in a javascript document that I have never seen before. It looks like this:

```
'1978-11-23T00:00:01.000Z'
```

Can someone explain what that 'T' and 'Z' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain what that 'T' and 'Z' mean?

The `T` is the delimiter between the date and time. The `Z` is a timezone, specifically timezone "Zulu" (GMT+00:00, e.g., Greenwich mean time). As of the latest specification (ES5), JavaScript has a [standard date/time format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) which is derived from a simplified version of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (although it handles the absence of a timezone differently from the ISO standard). (Prior to ES5, there was no standard string form for dates in JavaScript at all, amazingly.)

> How to interpret this date format?

If you're using an engine that implements this part of ES5, you can just pass that string into the [`Date(value)` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2):

```
var dt = new Date('1978-11-23T00:00:01.000Z');
```

If you're using an engine that doesn't yet implement this part of the standard (IE8 or earlier, for instance), you'll have to use a regular expression to break out the individual parts of the string, convert them to numbers, and feed them into the [`Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1), or use an add-on library to parse it for you.